# How can I pass a token (string) from an input page to service and use it for API requests in Angular2?

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a project, in which I will have a homepage, a service and a page where the API requests are called.
I want to take a string from tha input fild and pass it to service to use it as token in Authentication.
The problem is that it seems tha when I route to the other page the token is lost.

**Homepage.html**

```
  <div class="center">

   <h1 id="title" class="title">Είσοδος</h1>

   &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
 &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="center">
<p class="sub-title">Εισάγετε το token σας </p>
</div>
<div class="center">


    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;


    &nbsp;



          <label  class="label" for="input-password">Token:  </label>

        <input nbInput
        fullWidth type="text" (ngModel)="token" #passa>



    </div>
  <div class = "center">


    <pre>

    </pre>
    <pre></pre> 

    <button class="button1"  (click)="pass(passa)"> 
      Είσοδος
    </button>  

  </div>
```

**Homepage.component.ts**

```
 import {Component, OnDestroy,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';
    import { ParkingService } from '../../../services/parking.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';



    @Component({
        selector: 'ngx-homepage',
        styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss'],
        templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
        providers: [ParkingService]

      })

      @Injectable()
      export class HomepageComponent {

        a:string;
      constructor (public parkingService: ParkingService, public root:Router) { 

      }

            pass(passa)
              {

              this.a= passa.value;
              window.alert(this.a);
              this.parkingService.setUserToken(this.a);

              this.root.navigate(['/pages/iot-dashboard']);

              }
```

**Service.ts**

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, ErrorHandler, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    BehaviorSubject,
    Observable,
    throwError as observableThrowError,
    Subject,
  } from 'rxjs';

  import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpHeaders,
  } from '@angular/common/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import { catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NbAuthSimpleToken, NbAuthService, NbAuthSimpleInterceptor } from '@nebular/auth';
//import {HomeComponent} from '../pages/dashboard/homepage/homepage.component';



@Injectable()
  export class ParkingService{
    public userToken$: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
     public token: string;



    constructor( private httpclient: HttpClient){
      this.userToken$.subscribe( token => {
        this.token = token;
console.log(this.token);
  });



    }

    setUserToken(token: string) {
      this.userToken$.next(token);
  }




        getparkingDetails(): Observable<any>{


          console.log(this.token);
        const httpOptions = {


            headers: new HttpHeaders({

              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + this.token,
            }),
          };

          return this.httpclient.get<any>("https://socialpark.iti.gr:8005/parking_sites/management", httpOptions).pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandler));
        }

        errorHandler(error: any) {
          if (error == 404)
          return Observable.throw(error ||  "Please provide proper credentials");
        }



        addparkingDetails(parkingSite: any): Observable<any>{

          const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + this.token,
            }),
          };
          return this.httpclient.post<any>(
            "https://socialpark.iti.gr:8005/parking_sites/management/updates",
            parkingSite,
            httpOptions).pipe(
              catchError(this.errorHandlerup));

            }

        errorHandlerup(error: any) {
          if (error == 422){
          return Observable.throw(error ||  "Duplicate licence plate found during insertion.");
          }
          else if (error == 401) {
            return Observable.throw(error || "Please provide proper credentials");

          } 
        }


      }
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
     import {Component, OnDestroy, ErrorHandler, OnInit} from 
   '@angular/core';
    import { NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme';
    import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators' ;
    import { SolarData } from '../../@core/data/solar';
    import {ParkingService} from '../../services/parking.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { stringify } from 'querystring';
    import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

    interface CardSettings {
      title: string;
      iconClass: string;
      type: string;
    }


    @Component({
      selector: 'ngx-dashboard',
      styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
      templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',

      providers: [ParkingService]
    })
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnDestroy,OnInit {

      selectedMoments1 = new Date();
      selectedMoments2 = new Date();
      selectedMoment = new Date();
      time1 = new Date();
      time3 = new Date();
      getdata: any;
      parkingid: string;
      parkingpost: any;
      allspots: any;
      getdatadis: any;
      allspotsdis: any;

      constructor(private parkingService: ParkingService, private router: Router,) {




      }
      ngOnInit(){

        this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(
          data=>
          {
          this.getdata = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional)
          this.allspots = JSON.parse(data.space_total.conventional)
          this.getdatadis = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.disabled)
          this.allspotsdis = JSON.parse(data.space_total.disabled)
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);

        },
        );

      }

      plus(t1,t2,selected,a){

        let plate:string = a.value;
        const a1 = t1.value.slice(0,2);
        const b1 = parseInt(a1);

        const a2=t2.value.slice(0,2);
        const b2 = parseInt(a2);



        if(selected=="general"){

              for (let index: number= b1; index <=b2; index++) {

                this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


                  data=>
                  {
                  //this.getdata = data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional
                  //this.allspots = JSON.parse(data.space_total.conventional)
                  //this.getdatadis = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.disabled)
                 // this.allspotsdis = JSON.parse(data.space_total.disabled)
                  this.parkingid = data._id
                  this.parkingpost={
                    "parking_site_id": this.parkingid,
                    "licence_plate": plate ,
                    "indexes": [index],
                    "operation_type":"append",
                    "spot_type": "conventional" 

                  }

                    //this.parkingpost=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parkingpost)); 
            this.parkingService.addparkingDetails(this.parkingpost).subscribe(
              response => {
              //this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
              window.alert("Επιτυχής ανανέωση στοιχείων");

              setTimeout(() => {
                this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(

                  data=>
                  {
                  this.getdata = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional)
                  this.allspots = JSON.parse(data.space_total.conventional)
                  this.getdatadis = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.disabled)
                  this.allspotsdis = JSON.parse(data.space_total.disabled)
                },
                error => {
                  console.error(error);

                },
                );
            }, 3000);
            },
            error => {

              console.error(error);




            },
            );

                  },
                  error => alert(error)
                ); 





        } 
          }
        else{
              for (let index: number= b1; index <=b2; index++) {

                this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


                  data=>
                  {
                  this.getdata = data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional
                  this.parkingid = data._id
                  this.parkingpost={
                    "parking_site_id": this.parkingid,
                    "licence_plate": plate ,
                    "indexes": [index],
                    "operation_type":"append",
                    "spot_type": "disabled" 

                  }

                    //this.parkingpost=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parkingpost)); 
            this.parkingService.addparkingDetails(this.parkingpost).subscribe(
              response => {
              //this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
              window.alert("Επιτυχής ανανέωση στοιχείων");
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


                  data=>
                  {
                  this.getdata = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional)
                  this.allspots = JSON.parse(data.space_total.conventional)
                  this.getdatadis = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.disabled)
                  this.allspotsdis = JSON.parse(data.space_total.disabled)
                },
                error => {
                  console.error(error);

                },
                );
            }, 2000);
            },
            error => {
              console.error(error);

            },
            );

                  },
                  error => alert(error)
                ); 

            }

      }


      }

      plin(t3,selected2,b)
      {
        const plate = b.value;
        const a3=t3.value.slice(0,2);
        const b3 = parseInt(a3);
        window.alert(b3);
        window.alert(plate);
        if(selected2=="general"){
          this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


            data=>
            {
            this.getdata = data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional
            this.parkingid = data._id
            this.parkingpost={
              "parking_site_id": this.parkingid,
              "licence_plate": plate ,
              "indexes": [b3],
              "operation_type":"remove",
              "spot_type": "conventional" 

            }

              //this.parkingpost=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parkingpost)); 
      this.parkingService.addparkingDetails(this.parkingpost).subscribe(
        response => {
        //this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
        window.alert("Επιτυχής ανανέωση στοιχείων");
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


            data=>
            {
            this.getdata = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional)
            this.allspots = JSON.parse(data.space_total.conventional)
            this.getdatadis = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.disabled)
            this.allspotsdis = JSON.parse(data.space_total.disabled)
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);

          },
          );
      }, 2000);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);

      },
      );

            },
            error => alert(error)
          ); 


        }
        else{
          this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


            data=>
            {
            this.getdata = data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional
            this.parkingid = data._id
            this.parkingpost={
              "parking_site_id": this.parkingid,
              "licence_plate": plate ,
              "indexes": [b3],
              "operation_type":"remove",
              "spot_type": "disabled" 

            }

              //this.parkingpost=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parkingpost)); 
      this.parkingService.addparkingDetails(this.parkingpost).subscribe(
        response => {
        //this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
        window.alert("Επιτυχής ανανέωση στοιχείων");
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(


            data=>
            {
            this.getdata = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.conventional)
            this.allspots = JSON.parse(data.space_total.conventional)
            this.getdatadis = JSON.parse(data.spaces_occupied_current_slot.disabled)
            this.allspotsdis = JSON.parse(data.space_total.disabled)
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);

          },
          );
      }, 2000);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);

      },
      );

            },
            error => alert(error)
          ); 


          // new_conv = p.spaces_occupided.disabled[b3].remove(plate);
          //service.post(new_conv);
        }
      }




      private alive = true;



      //constructor(private themeService: NbThemeService,
        //          private solarService: SolarData) {
        //this.themeService.getJsTheme()
         // .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
          //.subscribe(theme => {
            //this.statusCards = this.statusCardsByThemes[theme.name];
        //});

        //this.solarService.getSolarData()
          //.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
          //.subscribe((data) => {
            //this.solarValue = data;
         // });
      //}

      ngOnDestroy() {
       this.alive = false;
      }


    }
```

**The console.log(this.token) in constructor is printing 'null' ,token and then null again**

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vceVb.png)

Comment: Hey @Anastasia Welcome to the community. I don't see here where have you called the getParkingDetails() method. I assume maybe it is in the page component you have mentioned. could you also please add the code of that component too? Thanks

Comment: Hello @MilanLakhani thank you for your answer. The problem isnt't the request, the problem is the authentiction. If I use a specific token it works, but I need to take the token by "this.token" and it seems to be null

Comment: I am not stating that the problem might be in request. But as you are getting the value null which means that token isn't set when you are calling getParkingDetails( where you are logging token ). So it might be the case where you might be calling getParkingDetails() before actually setting the token in the service. So maybe you should look to that issue or put the pagecomponent code.

Comment: @MilanLakhani ok I just post it